# How do I view the entirety of a codex entry in Assassin's Creed: Valhalla?

Tags: xbox-one, assassins-creed-valhalla

[image: Screenshot of In assassin's Creed Valhalla]

How am I supposed to scroll this codex entry article down so I can read the whole thing? The right stick icon is disabled as you can see in the screenshot and nothing I press moves focus to the article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You move the circle focus ring (left thumbstick) over to the right (hover over the text) and you can then use the right thumbstick to scroll up and down.

So right thumbstick to scroll up and down whatever list the focus ring is hovering over (right now in your screen capture, you're using the right thumbstick to scroll up and down the codex headings)

Comment: I had to change the input mode from focused to free, or something like that. Otherwise I couldn't move the focus ring.